# Prestashop how to get groups name for every language via API

Tags: php, prestashop

Prestashop 1.7 to 8 version.
I can't get the customer groups names in different languages via API using PS webservice library, instead I'm able to retrieve all the other fields by following the PS documentation examples.
See the following xml API GET response, my trouble is related to the multiple language tags inside name tag.
I could not find any working php code to get something simple like this array:

```
$groupNames = ("1" => 'Visitatore", "2" => "Visitor", "3" => "Visiteur")
```

where 1,2,3 are the language id of my shop

Any ideas? Thanks for help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <group>
        <id>
            <![CDATA[1]]>
        </id>
        <reduction>
            <![CDATA[0.00]]>
        </reduction>
        <price_display_method>
            <![CDATA[1]]>
        </price_display_method>
        <show_prices>
            <![CDATA[1]]>
        </show_prices>
        <date_add>
            <![CDATA[2020-10-07 15:20:23]]>
        </date_add>
        <date_upd>
            <![CDATA[2020-10-15 16:00:34]]>
        </date_upd>
        <name>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="https://myshop.it/api/languages/1">
                <![CDATA[Visitatore]]>
            </language>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="https://myshop.it/api/languages/2">
                <![CDATA[Visitor]]>
            </language>
            <language id="3" xlink:href="https://myshop.it/api/languages/3">
                <![CDATA[Visiteur]]>
            </language>
        </name>
    </group>
</prestashop>
```

here's my code..

```
try {            
    $webService = new \PrestaShopWebservice($activeShop->url, $activeShop->apikey, false);        
    // call to retrieve all customer groups
    $xml = $webService->get([
       'resource' => 'groups',
        ]);
    } catch (\PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
        $exception = str($ex->getMessage());
        return $exception;
    }   
    $resources = $xml->groups->children();
    foreach ($resources as $resource) {
    $attributes = $resource->attributes();
    $resourceId = $attributes['id'];  
    try {                     
     // call to retrieve groups fields
    $xml2 = $webService->get([
       'resource' => 'groups',
       'id' => $resourceId
        ]);                
     } catch (\PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
       $exception = str($ex->getMessage());                   
       return $exception;
     }
    $groupsFields = $xml2->group->children();                                 
    $name = $groupsFields->name;
    $name2 = $name->language;
    //from here is the issue .. how to get the names ? see dump below
    // I tried name2->attributes but it doesn't work
    // .....
  }
```

```
dump of $groupsFields --- all fields are easyily accessible, ex: $groupsFields->reduction
SimpleXMLElement {#1378 ▼
  +"id": "1"
  +"reduction": "0.00"
  +"price_display_method": "1"
  +"show_prices": "1"
  +"date_add": "2020-10-07 15:20:23"
  +"date_upd": "2020-10-15 16:00:34"
  +"name": SimpleXMLElement {#1386 ▶}
}

dump of $name2 - how to manage @attributes ???????
SimpleXMLElement {#1379 ▼ 
  +"@attributes": array:1 [▶]
  +"0": "Visitatore"
  +"1": "Visitor"
  +"2": "Visiteur"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution..

```
// retrieves the names of the groups in the different languages                       $name = $groupsFields->name;
$languages = $name->language;
$groupNames = null;
  foreach ($languages as $language) {
  $groupNames[] = array((string)$language['id'] => (string)$language );
  }
```